# How to get POSIX strerror_r instead of GNU version?

Tags: ubuntu, g++, posix, glibc

How do I get the POSIX [strerror_r](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/strerror.3.html) instead of GNU version?

I'm compiling with g++ on Ubuntu 8.04 with glibc version 2.7 ( based on what's in  ).

**Edit**

On the above man page it says:

Feature Test Macro Requirements for glibc (see feature_test_macros(7)):

```
   The XSI-compliant version of strerror_r() is provided if:
   (_POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 200112L || _XOPEN_SOURCE >= 600) && ! _GNU_SOURCE
   Otherwise, the GNU-specific version is provided.
```

It then says in [feature_test_macros(7)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html):

```
   If no feature test macros are explicitly defined, then the following feature
   test macros are defined by default: _BSD_SOURCE, _SVID_SOURCE, _POSIX_SOURCE,
   and _POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809L (200112L in glibc versions before 2.10; 199506L in
   glibc versions before 2.4; 199309L in glibc versions before 2.1).
```

So I should be getting the POSIX version, but I'm getting the GNU one instead.

Comment: Are you sure none of your header files or 3. party headers defines e.g. `_GNU_SOURCE` ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the header `string.h`:

```
/* Reentrant version of `strerror'.
   There are 2 flavors of `strerror_r', GNU which returns the string
   and may or may not use the supplied temporary buffer and POSIX one
   which fills the string into the buffer.
   To use the POSIX version, -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600 or -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L
   without -D_GNU_SOURCE is needed, otherwise the GNU version is
   preferred.  */
```

Note, be careful when using GNU extensions, turn them on (`_GNU_SOURCE`) last, before including the headers that you want it to affect (or undefine it strategically). No need to worry if not using GNU extensions, though.

Generally, if GNU deviates from POSIX in default behavior, you'll see some comments in the header to indicate how you can get the POSIX behavior. Its also (usually) documented in the glibc manual, but that doesn't always make it to the highly condensed man pages.

**Edit**

Try this simple test:

```
#include <string.h>
#ifdef _GNU_SOURCE
#error "Something turned it on!"
#endif
```

Or more directly

```
#ifdef _GNU_SOURCE
#undef _GNU_SOURCE
#endif
#include <string.h>
```

If `_POSIX_C_SOURCE={version}` is defined, you *should* have the POSIX version unless something else caused the GNU version to be favored.

The only thing I can think of that would do that is `_GNU_SOURCE`. I'm sure this isn't on your command line flags, you would have seen it. It could be that another library that is included has turned it on.

That's what I meant about the extensions being 'tricky' when requesting that POSIX implementations be favored, even if you aren't the one turning them on.

**Edit**

If something is turning on `_GNU_SOURCE` (I can't recall if boost does or not, I don't use c++ nearly as much as I do C), you probably want to allow it to do so. You can use `--undef "[macro]" -U[macro]` from the command line. However, that won't work if the library code looks like this:

```
#ifndef _GNU_SOURCE
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#endif

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#ifdef _GNU_SOURCE
#error "It didn't work"
#endif

int main(void)
{
   return 0;
}
```

The issue is, by the time your code actually includes `string.h`, something else has already turned on extensions and included it. Include guards naturally prevent you from including it twice.

Try explicitly turning off `_GNU_SOURCE` and including `string.h` prior to *anything* else. This prevents other libraries from turning those extensions on. However, those libraries might not work without them. Some code just 'expects' GNU behavior, and does not include fallback to POSIX.

I've experienced similar frustration with library code that does not work without `asprintf()`.

Comment: What I don't understand is that in the documentation it says that `_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L` is defined by default ( see the edit to my OP ), so I don't understand why I'm getting the GNU version.

Comment: I tried the first one, and apparently something is turning it on.  Nothing in my code is turning it on, so it must be something from either glibc, stdlib++ ( STL ) or Boost I assume.  Is there a way to undef it globally from the command line?

Comment: @Robert - I don't believe glibc / stdlib++ turns extensions on by default. Its probably coming from boost, or another library. If your string header is included first (before boost), with `-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE`, it should be _off_. See my edit.

Comment: +1 So I guess that I'll need to try including `<cstring>` before any of the Boost headers and see if that helps and doesn't in the process break Boost.

Comment: I ran a test in which I checked `_GNU_SOURCE` as the very first statement in the file, and apparently it's defined by default by g++.  The question is, will turning it off from the command line break stuff...

Comment: @Robert - In boost? I doubt it. Other stuff that isn't as well tested (or written) that does no fall back if common extensions aren't enabled .. its hard to say. The 'best' option might be to implement your own reentrant version of strerror(), which would not be that difficult. Then again, if nothing breaks .. no need to fix it :)

Comment: @Tim Post - No, not Boost, g++.  I put the test as the first statement in the file before any `#include`'s.  It seems like g++ is defining it.

Comment: @Robert - I mean that having it undefined would probably not break boost.

Comment: @RobertS.Branes Turning it of breaks libstdc++ for me.

Comment: g++ undeed turns on `_GNU_SOURCE` by default, and turning it off manually breaks libstdc++. Apparently, libstdc++ relies on specific definitions in other headers that only show up when `_GNU_SOURCE` is defined.

Answer (score 4):

This is an implementation-specific workaround.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
    {
#endif
    extern 
    int __xpg_strerror_r(int errcode,char* buffer,size_t length);
    #define strerror_r __xpg_strerror_r

#ifdef __cplusplus
    }
#endif
```

Comment: why give your kernel version when we're talking userland?

Answer (score 2):

While it's not required to be thread-safe by the standard, I can't imagine any way a sane person could write a non-thread-safe `strerror`. What do people do, `gunzip` the error strings at runtime or something?! A good `strerror` should be returning a pointer either to string constants in the standard library, or to constant `mmap`'d memory from the locale messages file.

Apologies that this isn't a real answer, but if you don't care about absolute theoretical portability you might check and see if all the implementations you care about have sane `strerror` behavior, and if so, just use that instead.

Comment: You're funny.  That second sentence had me LOL'ing.  Wow, I can't believe I just typed LOL'ing, damn there it is again.  You'd think I was 13 typing stuff like that.  Bahh, it probably just too much beer and too many unit tests in one night.

Comment: Another function like this with a ridiculous `_r` variant is `readdir`. There's a perfectly good `DIR` structure to contain the buffer (or a pointer to a dynamically-allocated-per-thread buffer if people really insist on reading a single `DIR` from multiple threads) and absolutely no justification for adding `readdir_r` (with a clunky interface).

Comment: The man page even lists examples: "unknown error NNN". And that's *without* translation.

Comment: FWIW the standard has been updated to require `readdir` to be thread-safe. Hoping `strerror` will be next.

Comment: @o11c: Indeed, generated messages for invalid error numbers are the obvious case where a non-immutable string would be returned. A compromise I'm proposing for standardization is requiring `strerror` to be thread-safe only when the error number passed to it is valid.