# compatibility of strerror_r on different platforms

Tags: linux, bsd, errno, strerror

I am trying to use strerror_r() function for getting error string corresponding to an error code and I am targeting BSD and Linux platforms, but the man page of strerror_r() says:

```
int strerror_r(int errnum, char *buf, size_t buflen);
                   /* XSI-compliant */

char *strerror_r(int errnum, char *buf, size_t buflen);
                   /* GNU-specific */
```

So I am not sure of it's compatibility(the XSI compliancy and GNU specific compliancy) on different platforms, I would appreciate if you could help me telling which platforms is it compatible on ? On which platforms I get which version out of the above ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get POSIX strerror\_r instead of GNU version?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052041/how-to-get-posix-strerror-r-instead-of-gnu-version)

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis nope not duplicate, the other answer tries to answer how to use POSIX version instead of GNU while this is asking for compatiblity.

Comment: Regarding the function return value, the GNU version, `char` would get promoted to `int` in line with the C Standard. Using that along with a macro wrapper to use either, as in a `#ifdef` that is.

Comment: @t0mm13b it would be great if can you explain with an example what you are saying.