# How to get a C file using the POSIX version of strerror_r when mixed with C++ files

Tags: gcc, g++, posix, gnu

This question relates to [How to get POSIX strerror_r instead of GNU version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052041/how-to-get-posix-strerror-r-instead-of-gnu-version). However, the strerror_r is in a C file, but other files are C++ files.

To make sure all the files compile and link smoothly, I choose to use the same g++ compiler and compilation flags. That breaks the default version of strerror_r.

Is using same compiler and flags necessary? If I use gcc to compile the C file, but g++ to compile the C++ files, will they link properly not breaking libstdc++, as the referred question states or implies it may break?

Since both the C file and C++ files are from existing projects, rolling my own version of strerror_r is not preferred.

Edit: Just posted the code and question to github at https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/issues/440. I don't see a neat solution to this problem since my reading of the referred SO question is either roll-your-own, or risk broken libstdc++ (which I have no idea what could be broken). Can I create a specific case and show the code that breaks? Not at the moment yet. If someone can tell me which part of libstdc++ can be broken by undef _GNU_SOURCE, that might give me some hint too. I do see weird behaviors but have not narrowed down to a minimal and verifiable piece. It's on an embedded system with little debugging ability. If I came down to something solid I sure will post it here.

Comment: If you are getting an error,  please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

After some research and thinking I believe the answers are as the following, though somebody may disagree to some extent.

- Is using same compiler and flags necessary? It is not necessary though preferred. As long as the compilers and flags are compatible each C or C++ files can be compiled differently, and they should link properly too.
- If I use gcc to compile the C file, but g++ to compile the C++ files, will they link properly not breaking libstdc++, as the referred question states or implies it may break? I guess the rules here are: [1] C++ code calls only C++ library. And [2] C code calls only C library and not to call C++ code or C++ library.