# Casting pointer to intptr_t and back

Tags: c, casting, c11

I am experimenting with using `_Generic` to make a thread-safe `strerror` function that is agnostic to using the XSI or GNU variants of `strerror_r`.  The XSI variant returns an `int` and modifies the contents of a buffer passed into it, while the GNU version returns a `char *`.

**strerror.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#include "strerror.h"

static inline char *strerror_r_gnu(int errnum, char *buf, size_t buflen);
static inline char *strerror_r_xsi(int errnum, char *buf, size_t buflen);

static inline char *strerror_r_gnu(int errnum, char *buf, size_t buflen) {

   // FUNKY CASTING TO SILENCE COMPILER WARNING BELOW
   return (char *)(intptr_t)strerror_r(errnum, buf, buflen);
}


static inline char *strerror_r_xsi(int errnum, char *buf, size_t buflen) {

   // Cast result to int to shut up compiler when using GNU strerror()
   int err = (int)strerror_r(errnum, buf, buflen);
   if (err) {
      snprintf(buf, buflen, "%s error", __func__);

      // If your buffer can't fit this error message, you deserve truncation
      buf[buflen-1] = '\0';
   }
   return buf;
}

char *strerror_p(int errnum, char *buf, size_t buflen) {
   return _Generic(strerror_r,
         int (*)(int, char *, size_t) : strerror_r_xsi(errnum, buf, buflen),
         char * (*)(int, char *, size_t) : strerror_r_gnu(errnum, buf, buflen)
         );

}
```

**strerror.h**

```
#ifndef STRERROR_H 
#define STRERROR_H

char *strerror_p(int errnum, char *buf, size_t buflen);

#endif // STRERROR_H
```

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include "strerror.h"

int main(void){

   const int buflen = 128;
   char buf[buflen]; // Flawfinder: ignore
   fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", strerror_p(EINVAL, buf, buflen));
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

in the `strerror_r_gnu` function, without casting the results of `strerror_r`, the compiler will spit out a warning `incompatible integer to pointer conversion returning 'int' from a function with result type 'char *'` when compiled with the XSI version of `strerror_r`.  Since this function will never get called when compiled against the XSI version of `strerror_r`, I do not care about the type mismatch, but I would like the silence the compiler about it.  Casting to `intptr_t` and then to `char *` silences the compiler warning.

The question is, when compiling with the GNU `strerror_r` that returns a `char *`, is it well-defined to cast the result to `intptr_t` and back to `char *`?

Comment: Why not use the preprocessor to select the appropriate code instead of *funky* casts?

Comment: @chqrlie A valid question.  Partly, I wanted to experiment with _Generic to see if a function could be used as a controlling expression in this manner.   I also had some uncertainty as to whether the current macro check would remain valid in the future, or if it may evolve in time and what is sufficient now is not sufficient in the future.  Most importantly, though, after implementing, I was curious as to the answer to the question I posed, regardless as to whether this implementation is the best solution to the `strerror_r` problem.

Comment: The real question is why this "XSI" returns `int`? I don't know these functions but brief research suggests that they the gcc and POSIX versions have different behavior? See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052041/how-to-get-posix-strerror-r-instead-of-gnu-version)

Comment: @Lundin The XSI version returns an `int` as an error code while the error string is put into a buffer passed into the function.  The GNU version is kind of odd in that it also has a buffer passed into it, but it's not guaranteed that it will even use the buffer, so you must use the returned `char *`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The question is, when compiling with the GNU strerror_r that returns a
>   char *, is it well-defined to cast the result to `intptr_t` and back to
>   char *?

Yes. The safety of such an operation is pretty much the definition of `intptr_t` in the standard:

[7.20.1.4 Integer types capable of holding object pointers](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.20.1.4)

> 1 The following type designates a signed integer type with the
>   property that any valid pointer to void can be converted to this type,
>   then converted back to pointer to void, and the result will compare
>   equal to the original pointer:
>
> ```
>      intptr_t
> ```

(Combine that with [6.2.5p28](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p28):

> A pointer to void shall have the same representation and alignment
>   requirements as a pointer to a character type.
>   Similarly, pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible
>   types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements.
>   All pointers to structure types shall have the same representation and
>   alignment requirements as each other. All pointers to union types
>   shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as each
>   other. Pointers to other types need not have the same representation
>   or alignment requirements.

)

Comment: I had come across 7.20.1.4, but because it specified void pointer, I was left unsure if it carried over.  If we accept that 6.2.5 means it is equally viable for `char *`, but does not say anything about other types, does that mean doing this type of casting with an `int *` rather than `char *` would not be well-defined?  Or is it legal to cast from `intptr_t` to any pointer type as long as alignment requirements are kept, therefore casting from any pointer type to `intptr_t` and back would be legal since the original pointer met the alignment requirments?

Comment: @ChristianGibbons Yes, casting with an `int *` rather than `char *` would NOT be well defined. The rest of 6.2.5p28 clarifies that (namely the last sentence). I've added it to the answer.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons, if you're still concerned, you can insert an intermediate cast to `void *`.  All object pointer types are required to be unchanged by round-trip conversion through `void *`.